# How many four-digit numbers can be arranged from the numbers {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, when each number can be repeated a maximum of 3 times?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I just can't wrap my head around this. Maybe I'm overthinking it. I tried to use permutations with indistinguishable objects but I failed. Please help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, figure out how many four-digit numbers there are with those digits. The first can be 1,2,3,4, and the other three can be any, so that gives $4\cdot5^3=500$.

Then we subtract the four digit numbers with four times the same digits, so 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, so there are four of them.

This gives 496 numbers.

Comment: Wow thanks a bunch. I never would've thought of subtracting four times-same digit numbers.